# C++ Error in XCode: in defining operator* "no viable overloaded operator *=" while *= has been tested and is functional

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For my project, I have a struct that represents a rational number as a fraction:

```
template <typename T=int>
struct rat
{
  T p; // Numerator
  T q; // Denominator
  rat(T x=0,T y=1): p(x), q(y){

  normalize();

}
```

Operators are overloaded as (within the struct):

```
rat<T>& operator*=(const rat<T>& a)
{
    this->p *= a.p;
    this->q *= a.q;
    normalize();
    return *this;
}
```

I've tested this code and it works.

Next, I want to define operations outside the scope of my struct:

```
template <typename T=int>
rat<T>& operator*(const rat<T>& a,const rat<T>& b)
    {
        return a*= b;
    }

template <typename T=int>
rat<T>& operator/(const rat<T>& a,const rat<T>& b)
    {
        return a/= b;
    }
```

However, SOME of these give an error when building in xcode "no viable overloaded operator". For instance, the / operator works. But the * does not.

I'm new to C++ (I have only been doing C++ for a week now) and I have no clue as to why some of them are OK and some are not. They're all defined the same...

If any more code is needed, I will provide it (but I tried to keep cluttering to a minimum).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `operator *` cannot work because it takes `a` by const reference and applies `operator *=` which is non-const on the object. You must take `a` by value, and return it by value (as you would otherwise return a reference to a local variable).

Comment: Copying `a` to a local variable would probably be better, I don't expect the multiplication operator to modify its arguments.

Comment: `rat<T> operator*(rat<T> a,const rat<T>& b)` indeed fixes my issues. Thank you, @WalterMisar and @NeilKirk. If I understand the C++ language correctly, passing `rat<T> a` makes a copy of the value in a.

Comment: @NeilKirk you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator `*=` is non `const` (since it changes its state) however in your free function you try to call `*=` on a `const&` which is why the overload can't be found. You should take parameter `a` by value so that it can have its `*=` operator called.

Additionally you should not be returning a reference from `operator*`, you're creating a new object which is not `a` nor `b`. Just return by value like so:

```
template <typename T=int>
rat<T> operator*(rat<T> a, const rat<T>& b)
{
    return a *= b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator *` cannot work because it takes `a` by const reference and applies `operator *=` which is non-const on the object. You must take `a` by value, and return it by value (as you would otherwise return a reference to a local variable).